# Two divs adaptive width

Tags: css

Im trying do this

```
<div>
    <div style="width:50%;"> first div </div>
    <div style="width:50%;"> second div </div>
</div>
```

Sometimes dynamically first or second div will not be displayed.
when first div is not displayed i need second assume width 100% and vice versa.
Can i do this just with css? min-weigth or max-width or something like that?

Comment: You can always use javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:only-child` pseudo class

```
.childDiv
{
    width:50%;
}
.childDiv:only-child
{
    width:100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="childDiv'> first div </div>
    <div class="childDiv'> second div </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the auto margin CSS properties:

```
.myClass
{
    margin:0px auto;
    width:50 //You can set this to whatever or take it out
}
```

And add to HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="myClass'> first div </div>
    <div class="myClass'> second div </div>
</div>
```